# XmlMediaTypeFormatter cannot write an object of type ObjectQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

When using EntityFramework and returning an IQueryable from an MVC 4 Web API Get action, the following error occurs when the XML serializer is set to use the old XmlSerializer (rather than DataContractSerializer).

> > XmlMediaTypeFormatter cannot write an object of type ObjectQuery

Is this a known issue?

Comment: I am having the same problem so it is not your set-up. It is this right?: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;`

Comment: Yeah, that's the setting I've used to switch to the old skool serializer [and get the error].

Comment: Yeah it is very annoying still trying to find another way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Too late for this question but for those who faced the same exception:

Your `ObjectQuery` class probably lacks a **default constructor**.

See my full answer here: [Xml Serialization cannot write an object of type 'x'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332800/xml-serialization-cannot-write-an-object-of-type-x/19332801#19332801)

Answer (score 0):

No.

You need to define `[Queryable]` attribute on your action. This requirement was added on RC and probably will be removed at RTM

---

## NOTE

OData support is [very unclear](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/359229) at the moment. I have created [PocoHttp](https://github.com/PocoHttp/PocoHttp) for consuming ASP.NET Web API's OData but paused development because of lack of clarity at the moment.

Comment: This attrib has always been there, it all stopped working when I changed the default XML serializer to XmlSerializer.

Comment: @LukePuplett OK. Yes, I have seen that. Sorry for not reading all of the question. I will delete the answer or update it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because one of the members of the class I was serialising was an interface. I didn't need to serialise that member so annotating it with a  [XmlIgnore] attribute fixed it.