# Xml Serialization cannot write an object of type 'x'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization

I want to serialize a class as a response in MVC Web API using `XmlFormatter` but I get the following exception while creating the response:

```
MediaTypeFormatter formatter = Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
HttpResponseMessage resp = Request.CreateResponse<Model>(HttpStatusCode.OK, value: modelObject, formatter: formatter);
```

The exception:

> The configured formatter 'System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.XmlMediaTypeFormatterTracer' cannot write an object of type 'Model'.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I digged the web for any clue of this error and found nothing after hours.

The answer was simple.

The `Model` class lacked a **default constructor** which caused a strange non-debug-able exception.

Further info: [Why XML-Serializable class need a parameterless constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267724/why-xml-serializable-class-need-a-parameterless-constructor)

Comment: Saved me hours of searching. Simple things like this. :-) Thank you!